# What jquery dialog box is your preferred one?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, dialog, modal-dialog

I have been googling for a while looking for good, flexible and easy to use dialog box, but still can't find the right one, maybe you guys can tell me what's your preferred one?

I found some of them:

[nyrodev](http://nyromodal.nyrodev.com/)

[this list has 10 examples](http://www.dreamcss.com/2009/06/10-jquery-lightbox-demo.html)

And jquery.Dialog() of course

Please, only one plugin for each answer so we can select the best one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery UI `dialog()` is very flexible and it's built in, why use anything else.

Comment: yes, it's very flexible but it moves your content outside form element, you can append it again but that bothers some time.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this one:

Facebox

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-facebox-opaque-background/